# Centering vertically text in different divs

Tags: html, css, centering, bulma

I'm currently using the Bulma CSS framework to style part of my dashboard page, one feature is a 'Widgets' feature that has three big containers that show key facts (e.g. the number of sales, new customers etc...).

The problem I'm having is that each 'title' is a different length, forcing the figure to be at a different height, ideally the 'figure' would be at the same level across all three DIVS.

[image: Screenshot of tiles]

If there's a way to align the figures in CSS that'd be great!
Thank you in advance for your help.

Example mockup, achieved by shortening the title:

[image: Example tiles mockup]

```css
/* Big Figure DIV for Associate Page */
.tile-title{
  margin-bottom:0 !important;
}

.bigFigure{
  margin: 7.5px auto;
}

.bigFigure p{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.4.2/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="tile is-ancestor">
  <div class="tile is-parent">
    <article class="tile is-child notification is-success">
      <p class="tile-title title is-5">New Customers</p>
      <div class="bigFigure">
        <p>4</p>
      </div>
      <small>You've captured 4 new customers in the last 7 days!</small>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="tile is-parent">
    <article class="tile is-child notification is-warning">
      <p class="tile-title title is-5">New Orders</p>
      <div class="bigFigure">
        <p>0</p>
      </div>
      <small>There haven't been any orders in the last 7 days.</small>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="tile is-parent">
    <article class="tile is-child notification is-danger">
      <p class="tile-title title is-5">Orders that delayed for shipping</p>
      <div class="bigFigure">
        <p>5</p>
      </div>
      <small>There are 5 order(s) that require shipping.</small>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be *somehow* independent from the headings line number, you can [`position: absolute;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) your number and `<small>` elements and align them from the bottom, e.g.:

```
.bigFigure {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}
```

Adjust the `bottom` value to your needs. `50%` should work well with up to 3 rows.

If your footer line number is constant, you can even take a fixed number instead of a percentage.

```css
article.tile {
  padding-bottom: 8em;
}

.tile-title {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.bigFigure {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}

.bigFigure p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.tile>small {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.4.2/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="tile is-ancestor">
  <div class="tile is-parent">
    <article class="tile is-child notification is-success">
      <p class="tile-title title is-5">New Customers</p>
      <div class="bigFigure">
        <p>4</p>
      </div>
      <small>You've captured 4 new customers in the last 7 days!</small>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="tile is-parent">
    <article class="tile is-child notification is-warning">
      <p class="tile-title title is-5">New Orders, that are so cool, that I need 3 lines.</p>
      <div class="bigFigure">
        <p>0</p>
      </div>
      <small>There haven't been any orders in the last 7 days.</small>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="tile is-parent">
    <article class="tile is-child notification is-danger">
      <p class="tile-title title is-5">Orders that delayed for shipping</p>
      <div class="bigFigure">
        <p>5</p>
      </div>
      <small>There are 5 order(s) that require shipping.</small>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Done! Cheers buddy :)

Comment: Thank you! Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a `min-height` on your `.tile-title` that allows for two lines of text in all cases.

```
.tile-title {
  margin-bottom:0 !important;
  min-height: 2.5em;
}
```

Comment: But what if the title is 3 or more lines?

Comment: So what you are actually asking for is that the number of lines allocated to each dashboard title is the maximum required number of lines for all dashboard titles in that row?  I can't really see a method of doing that unless you invoke some JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions is using js. You can set for all containers margin-top value of the container with the highes margin-top value. Just iterate throught all containers and select the container with the highest margin-top value. And then set this value for the rest conteiners.